# Item showed up twice in review queue

Tags: bug

Saw the review icon beckoning, so I clicked on it.  First "answer" was really a question (or possibly a personal message), so I recommended delete.  Went through the rest of the queue, and at the end, the same first one came back again.

Bug?

Comment: Do you have a link to the review or the answer?  Without it, we can only guess, but it is possible that the answer in question was flagged a 2nd time and reentered the review queue

Comment: If I have saved a link then, …. Two weeks later, I can’t even remember the topic.  wouldn’t it have stayed in the queue until it got enough votes?

Comment: Depends on the circumstances.  It could have left the queue for any number of reasons, and the come back because of another flag.  No counting out a bug, but there are also possibilities that aren't a bug